# To get rid of Icon in action bar/android

Tags: android, android-actionbar, icons

There are probably a dozen questions to this, still I cannot find an answer:

I have an app with several activities, each of which displays a standard action bar (should be so) with an android logo on the left.
Now how to get rid of that logo?

This is my Manifest xml, I think the work should be done there - have tried some as you can see, but to no avail.

```
        <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        package="com.example.pris"
        android:versionCode="1"
        android:versionName="1.0" >

        <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="13"
        android:targetSdkVersion="19" />
        android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"
        android:maxSdkVersion="19" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:label="@string/pris"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        android:icon="@android:color/transparent">
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.pris.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/pris" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.pris.ViewActivity"
            android:label="@string/pris"
            android:parentActivityName="com.example.pris.MainActivity" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.pris.DetailActivity"
            android:label="Priscus"
            android:parentActivityName="com.example.pris.ViewActivity" >
        </activity>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Can you post your AppTheme xml?

Comment: I have not found out where it IS yet I was under the impression that is just a standard theme in one of the libs which I am, by license, not allowed to change anyway

Comment: you can always customize it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
ActionBar ab = getActionBar();
if(ab != null) {
    ab.setIcon(new ColorDrawable(getResources().getColor(android.R.color.transparent)));
}
```

You can also use styles... actually you should prefer this version. In your styles.xml add this

```
<style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="android:Theme.Light">
</style>

<style name="AppTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">
    <item name="android:logo">@android:color/transparent</item>
</style>
```

Comment: I already tried that, however as you can see in my manifest.xml, my minimal version is sdk13 and this only works from sdk 14 onwards.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't take a look at minSdkVersion. You can use the style then. It will work for v11+ and since your min is 13, you will not have any problems. I just tried it out and it works.

Comment: Also about the api version 13... devices running Android 3.2 (API level 13) are REALLY rare, you can peacefully change minSdk to 14

Comment: I just tried what you suggested, no change whatsoever to the looks

Comment: about the api version - no I cannot, I did not set the version requirements

Comment: I had another bug what you suggest does work. However, as a result my actionbar seems to have vanished, was that intended?

Comment: No. You possibly removed android:label in your <application> tag. Also you can try getActionBar().setTitle() and let me know so I can further help you. In my case label is just fine

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/75521/discussion-between-bojan-kseneman-and-user1862770).